# extracting excel data into word template using python

Tags: python, excel

I am new to Python and I have a project I am working on. I have an excel spreadsheet with 90 rows of data. Each row has data for one country. I need to create a report in MS Word using data from the excel sheet. That is generate 90 reports, one for each country by populating data in various places of the word template from each row of the spreadsheet. 
Can this be done in Python and any pointers to get me started would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: yes, it can be done. Use the search engine of SO or outside search engins like Yahooooo. For next question.. post trail and error code. Be specific. That's how it works here.

Comment: Try [openpyxl](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/default/) and [python-docx](https://python-docx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).